# build 32-bit code on 64-bit linux system (kubuntu 18.04)

Tags: gcc, 32bit-64bit

I'm looking into porting a 32-bit AIX app to linux - doing proof of concept on my 64-bit Kubuntu desktop system.  I suppose I could build the app in 64-bit mode, but I'm afraid stuff might break (there are thousands of modules - it's a whole system of apps).

Anyway, I tried building a trivial app that just printf's sizeof int, short and long variables.  When I build it with 'cc test/c', it works, and sizeof reports 8-bytes for the long - so it's defaulting to 64-bit mode.  But when I try building it with 'cc -m32 test.c', it won't compile.

```
In file included from test.c:1:0:
/usr/include/stdio.h:27:10: fatal error: bits/libc-header-start.h: No such file or directory
 #include <bits/libc-header-start.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

So /usr/include/stdio.h does contain a reference to bits/libc-header-start.h, and there's no /usr/include/bits subdirectory.  But if that's the error, why doesn't the compiler complain about it when I run it without the -m32 flag?  I don't see any conditional logic around the #include in stdio.h, so what magic am I missing?  Is there another /usr/include tree that gets invoked with the -m32 flag?

Various posts on here address the issue of building for 32-bits on a 64-bit machine, but they're older posts and reference an older ubuntu base.  In any case, they suggest making sure that the proper libraries are loaded.  I've got these (and I assume if they were already there, my 32-bit build environment ought to be okay).  Is there something else I'm missing?

```
lib32gcc-4.8-dev/bionic 4.8.5-4ubuntu8 amd64
gcc-multilib/bionic-updates,bionic-security 4:7.4.0-1ubuntu2.3 amd64
```

Okay, I see that there's a 'bits' directory under /usr/include/x86-64-linux-gnu, but no parallel one for a non-64bit environment.

```
$ locate libc-header-start.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/libc-header-start.h
```

So what do I install to get that?  I've got these installed already:

```
libc6-dev-i386/bionic 2.27-3ubuntu1 amd64
libc6-dev-i386-amd64-cross/bionic-updates,bionic-updates 2.27-3ubuntu1cross1.1 all
libc6-dev-i386-cross/bionic-updates,bionic-updates 2.27-3ubuntu1cross1.1 all
libc6-dev-i386-x32-cross/bionic-updates,bionic-updates 2.27-3ubuntu1cross1.2 all
```

Comment: `I tried building a trivial app` Please post the sources. `cc -m32 test.c` Please try `gcc` in place of `cc` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had to install gcc-multilib and g++-multilib to get the missing stuff.  It works now.

Sorry if this is an old, old question.  Then again, somebody might need this info.

Oops.  That was enough to get a trivial application to build, but when I try to build my real application that uses 'curses', -lcurses ends up trying to pull in -ltinfo, and ld complains about that:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so when searching for -ltinfo
```

I don't call 'ld' directly.  My link statement is a call to 'cc -g -m32...', i.e., I'm counting on CFLAGS to produce a 32-bit binary, but the linker is still trying to pull in 64-bit stuff.  I tried calling 'ld' directly, but it doesn't like the -m32 flag.  Says it's an 'incompatible emulation mode'.

Is it really doable to build 32-bit binaries - or am I better off adjusting my configuration to just treat linux as a 64-bit platform and try to make that work...?

Comment: Uh, oh.  When I tried to build my non-trivial application, everything builds up until the final linking operation where it complains that //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so is incompatible with my project.
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltinfo